# Compute Metrics by using Deequ with Scala

Tags: scala, amazon-s3, amazon-deequ

I am new to `Scala` and `Amazon Deequ`. I have been asked to write a `Scala` code that would compute metrics (e.g. `Completeness`, `CountDistinct` etc) on constraints by using `Deequ` on source `csv` files stored on `S3`, and load the generated metrics in a Glue table which will be further used for reporting.

Can anyone please help me by pointing me in the right direction towards online resources that would help me achieve this ? I am new to both `Scala` and `Deequ`. So can anyone give me a sample `Scala` code and explain how the `deequ` libraries could be used etc ?

Please let me know if additional information is required to explain my question better.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for your interest in Deequ. The github page of deequ has information on how to get started with using it: https://github.com/awslabs/deequ

Additionally, there is a blogpost at the AWS blog with some examples as well: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/test-data-quality-at-scale-with-deequ/

Best,
Sebastian

Answer (score 0):

You can check the examples available here: https://github.com/awslabs/deequ/tree/master/src/main/scala/com/amazon/deequ/examples

Hope that helps.

Take some time to read the documentation too.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes